# Couldn't be downloaded IE

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer

Using a streamwriter we are exporting an .csv file.

```
        Response.ClearContent()
        Response.ClearHeaders()
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Peuters.csv")
```

This worked until IE11 was released. The code never changed but in IE I am getting the message at the bottom ".csv couldn't be downloaded". Then when I click on Retry it downloads the complete page, html & js, not the export file.

Anyone found a solution for this?

Yes, already tried these steps: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_7/couldnt-be-downloaded-appears-at-bottom-of-screen/ad51df58-bd7c-e011-9b4b-68b599b31bf5?msgId=61dd62bc-d592-4d54-8bd5-84a22ea59472
Didn't work.

Printscreen:
http://static.dyp.im/ufgMWUAXOb/1b257748b8489c192b53eae37623276c.png

Comment: Screenshot may help in this example or more details of the error?

Comment: Not allowed to add images. Added link to image.

Comment: My collegae found the solution. "Content-disposition" needs to be "Content-disposition:". By adding a ":" the downloading will succeed in IE11.

Comment: @Floris: It's still not working for me… Unable to download CSVs > 100 KB approx.

Comment: Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="fname.ext" as @Floris stated.

Comment: Have you tried the mime type of "text/csv" since your extension is .csv and your mime type is excel I.E. might pick up that it isn't actually an excel file and fail it?